# Show sub line(s) for eacht record in a report, SSRS (Sql Server Report Server 2012)

Tags: sql-server, report

I have a report where I am showing a list with companies. Each company has 1 or more addresses. I would like to show each address as a child record. Something like this:

- Parent record

  - child record
  - child record
  - child record
- Parent record

  - child record
- Parent record
- Parent record
- Parent record

  - child record
  - child record

for example there are 2 tables: Company and Address. There is a relation between these 2 tables from the address table a foreign key to the CompanyID.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need one **Tablix**; associate this with your **Dataset**.

Add a **Group** to the **Tablix**, based on *Company*; include a group header.

Now you should have one row for each *Company* and one row for each child *Address*. If you want indentation similar to your example merge the cells in the group header row.

The end result should like something like this:

[image]